# trigger select event programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a kendoUI dropdownlist defined as follows:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                  .Name("EditGroupSelector")
                  .BindTo(Model.Groups)
                   .Events(
                    events => events
                        .Select("onEditGroupSelected")
                   )
            )
```

i understand that the select event does not get triggered when i call the api as follows:

```
editGroupSelector.select(0);
```

after selecting the first item manually, i wanted to trigger the select event manually:

```
editGroupSelector.trigger("select");//api calls dont trigger events -> trigger it manually
```

this calls the event, but inside the eventhandler, i dont have my event and thus cannot get the new selected value:

```
function onEditGroupSelected(e) {
    var nameOfGroup = e.item.text();//e.item does not exist when triggered manually
}
```

how can i trigger the event so that i can actually use "e.item" inside my event-handler?

Comment: Do you know that if you want to get the `text` of the selected item you can do `editGroupSelector.text()` and works both if you picked the value manually or automatically?

Comment: For a question of `completeness` I've added an example on how to simulate the event, just in case you need it (or someone else)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

jQuery [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function has an optional parameter that are the arguments. You need to add it manually making it *compatible* with automatic invocation. You should add (at least) `item`.

**Example:**

If the `id` of your `dropDownList` is `dropdownlist` you can create the argument as follow:

```
dropDownList.select(3);
dropDownList.trigger("select",
        { item: $("li.k-state-selected", $("#dropdownlist-list")) }
);
```

**NOTE:** It's very important to note that the `list` decorator (open dropDownList) is not identified by the `id` that you defined (ex. `dropdownlist`) but the `id` followed by `-list` (Ex: `dropdownlist-list`). That's why jQuery selector is as `$("li.k-state-selected", $("#dropdownlist-list")`

Comment: and how can i add the item to the trigger("select")?

Comment: See **example** in the answer. Read **note**.

Comment: thanks for the example and the explaination - this one helped me alot!